# Show that a group is soluble

Tags: group-theory

I am wondering how I would go about showing that any group of order $p^2q$ or $pq^2$ is soluble, where $p,q$ are primes with $p<q$.
Could you give me a hint or outline for how to get started please? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know Sylow's theorems?

Comment: Yes I am aware of these, will they help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : Let $G$ be your group of order $p^2q$. Consider a $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$ and a $q$-Sylow subgroup $Q$ of $G$. You have to show that either $P$ or $Q$ is normal in $G$, in which case you'll have a normal series for $G$ ($p$-groups are solvable). To do this, try computing the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups and number of $q$-Sylow subgroups. If either of the one is $1$, then normality follows and you'll have a solution.

Comment: @user197311 Do you know how to [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) an answer?

Comment: no sorry I didn't realise I could do that (I'm new to stack exchange)